# Using composition to split component into base and child in React

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component that is a wrapper around ag-Grid:

```
<div className="ag-theme-material" style={{height: "100%"}}>
    <AgGridReact
        pagination
        paginationPageSize={this.props.Size}
        columnDefs={this.props.Col}
        rowData={this.props.Row}
    />
</div>
```

I want to create a separate wrapper but without the pagination feature. As such I want a base class with the common features from which the two children (with and without paging) can inherit from. I know inheritance is not used much in React, so I'm wondering how to achieve the same effect using composition. Thanks!

Comment: You can use a Higher order component (HOC) for this.

Comment: what are the common features? so we can suggest what's the best way for that.

Comment: Pagination feature for now

Comment: @UtsavPatel can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the compound components pattern, where you provide basic features for your component, and the user can use more features as he preferred.

the code would be something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDom from 'react-dom'
class AgGridReact extends Component {

  static Paginator = (props list) => (...) // some jsx that represents the paginator
  render() {
    return <>
      /** your grid jsx code here **/

      // other features code
      React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
              React.cloneElement(child, {
        // props you need to pass for the components
      }),
    )
  }
    </>
  }


        // the usage of this component will be:

        <AgGridReact {...props}>
            // the user can git rid of this if without paginator
           <AgGridReact.Paginator /> 
        </AgGridReact>
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand. `// props you need to pass for the components` is this meant to include the props for child or parent?

Comment: In this case, the props you need to pass to Paginator (the child)